# Round java double

Tags: java, math, double, rounding

I have created a Bayes Classifier, which essentially just returns double values.

However, these doubles are massive, e.g : 2.834096154725778E73.

I don't know much about the E scientific notation, and I just want to have a usable double which I can use in other aspects of my code ( I want to use the values for fuzzy logic).
I've had a look online, but what I have tried hasn't worked.

I basically just want to have a much smaller representation of the double specified above.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's a big number.  How could you possibly represent it as a small number?  This is like saying you want the population of the world expressed as a number between 0 and 100.

Comment: This isn't clear.  You have this value in a variable?  Then what is the issue?

Comment: *I have created a Bayes Classifier [...] I don't know much about the E scientific notification* `o_O` Kidding aside...what do you exactly want? To print the numbers with fewer digits?

Comment: I was hoping I could round the number somehow - but I have no idea what that double value actually is (with the E).

Comment: E means "times 10 to the."  The number is 2.834... * 10^73.  It's not clear whether you ought to actually care how large the numbers are; if they're meaningless, who cares if they're meaninglessly big?

Comment: @matt It's called scientific notation: `4.34e52` means `4.34·10^52`

Comment: And by smaller number I obviously meant fewer digits, but thanks David for being helpful.

Comment: 28340961547257780000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: haha sorry, yeah I meant notation!!

Comment: What makes this number unusable for the rest of your program? What goes wrong if you just use it as-is?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a format for rounding it.

Something like:

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
    df.format(0.912385); // or any big number
```

And then, you will have your number, but rounded...

Comment: Sorry, I was in kind of a rush when I downvoted this earlier.  The OP has a 74 digit number.  Doubles this big are always whole numbers, because doubles only have a precision of about 15-16 decimal digits.  Showing them how to format it with 5 decimal places isn't very helpful - these decimal places will always be zero, and this solution won't do any rounding at all.

Comment: There's no need of being rude... It was only an idea.